# Unity broken after regular updates

Tags: unity, updates, restart

Today I updated Ubuntu 12.04 with the Update Manager as usual. After that I restarted the system as required. When I logged in again the sidebar has only the trash can, the dash button and the switch workspaces button. No other shortcuts appear at all.
The top bar is there but has nothing. Not even the power symbol. Finally on the desktop no icons appear, right clicking does nothing and using Ctr+Alt+T doesn't bring up the console.
I restarted the computer several times and it's always the same. Help?

edit:
I solved it. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter the terminal. Then I used the last tip [in this video](http://youtu.be/hwFG9XpdYEg?t=52s) and it worked i.e. I typed
`sudo setsid service lightdm restart`

Comment: If you have solved it like you said then you should put your solution as an answer so others having similar problems can easily find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP solved it himself and says:

> I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the
>   terminal. Then I used the last tip in [this video](http://youtu.be/hwFG9XpdYEg?t=52s) and it worked
>   i.e. I typed `sudo setsid service lightdm restart`.

Comment: However it did work only temporarily as next time I turned the pc on the problem persisted. After a few tries I eventually decided to upgraded to 12.10 and it's now working fine (as it used to).